# MemSQL - why can't I do a cross-database insert into .. select

Tags: singlestore

I'm trying to do a simple insert with a field list from a table in one database to a table in another.

```
insert into db_a.target_table (field1,field2,field3) select field1,field2,field3 from db_b.source_table;
```

The error message seems straight-forward..

> MemSQL does not support this type of query: Cross-database INSERT ... SELECT

Oddly enough, this example does work:

```
insert into db_a.target_table select * from db_b.source_table;
```

But this seems like such a common scenario.  Has anyone run into a similar issue, and were you able to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't allowed because it is difficult to keep such queries transactional; multi-statement transactions are used internally to guarantee transactionality of the single insert-select (if one partition fails (dup key or something), we want to rollback everything!).  Since we don't have cross-db multi-statement transactions (yet!), we don't have cross-db insert-select (yet!).

Stay tuned for nicer solutions.

However, if you REAAALY want to do this, here is what you do.  However,

PROCEED AT YOUR OWN RISK.  THIS IS NOT A SUPPORTED PROCEEDURE.

But it should work.

1) On `db_b`, create a table with the same columns as `source_table`, but make the shard key `SHARD()`.

2) On `db_a`, run `SHOW PARTITIONS`.

3) For each of those partitions, create a connection to `db_a_<ordinal>` on the host and port listed in `SHOW PARTITIONS`.  Run `SHOW DATABASES` on that connection and you'll see some databases called `db_b_<another>`.  Pick one, doesn't matter which.  Run `INSERT INTO db_b<another>.source_table SELECT * from db_a_<ordinal>.source_table`.

3.5) At this point, you haven't yet written to a table you care about, but now we will.  Look at `db_b.source_table`.  Is everything correct?  Is all the data there?  Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and double check the shard key is `SHARD KEY ()` (it should be in comments).  Everything look good?  Ok, we can proceed.

4) After you're done doing this for EVERY partition, you can do `INSERT INTO db_b.target_table (cols) SELECT cols from db_b.source_table`, or whatever you want.

Good luck!